# Правильно ли написано предложение

Tags: общие-вопросы

Правильно ли составлено следующее предложение?

*В заседании ВЕЭС участвовали президенты России Владимир Путин, Беларуси Александр Лукашенко, Казахстана Нурсултан Назарбаев, Армении Серж Саргсян, а также премьер-министр Кыргызстана Сапар Исаков.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заседании  ВЕЭС участвовали президенты  Владимир Путин (Россия), Александр Лукашенко (Беларусь), Нурсултан Назарбаев (Казахстан), Серж Саргсян (Армения), а также премьер-министр Киргизии Сапар Исаков.

Comment: На мой взгляд, здесь неверно расставлены акценты. Наименования стран важнее имен президентов. Сравните: *спортсмен имярек (Росссия)*. Политика - не спорт.

Comment: Об акцентах трудно судить, нужен контекст, а вот текст должен быть по возможности краток и информативен, он должен читаться быстро и легко,  без остановок на повторах и тире. Современный пользователь не читает отдельные  слова, а воспринимает содержание целыми блоками.

Comment: В принципе порядок слов: Президент Имя Фамилия мне кажется неправильным. Как звание:   президент Фамилия, как должность: Президент Страна (Имя) Фамилия. А в данном тексте – должность.

Comment: Вот решение в Вашем стиле: В заседании ВЕЭС участвовали президенты России (Владимир Путин), Беларуси (Александр Лукашенко), Казахстана (Нурсултан Назарбаев), Армении (Серж Саргсян), а также премьер-министр Киргизии Сапар Исаков.

Comment: Хороший вариант, мне нравится.

Comment: Мне кажется все-таки, что неверно имя и фамилию заключать в скобки,  более подходят предыдущие варианты, которые написали Артем Луговой и Арина. Остальные варианты тоже рассмотрела. Всех благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 3):

В заседании участвовали президенты стран-членов ВЕЭС — Владимир Путин (Россия), Александр Лукашенко (Белоруссия), Нурсултан Назарбаев (Казахстан), Серж Саргсян (Армения), а также премьер-министр Киргизии Сапар Исаков.

С поправкой на комментарий...

На заседании ВЕЭС присутствовали президенты стран-участниц ЕЭС — В. Путин (Россия), А. Лукашенко (Белоруссия), Н. Назарбаев (Казахстан), С. Саргсян (Армения), а также премьер-министр Киргизии С. Исаков.

Comment: Членами ВЕЭС являются не страны, а их руководители. ВЕЭС - высший оргам Евразийского экономического союза (ЕАЭС). Страны являются челнами ЕАЭС.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, лучше переписать это предложение. Вот один из вариантов:

*В заседании ВЕЭС участвовали президенты: России — Владимир Путин, Беларуси — Александр Лукашенко, Казахстана — Нурсултан Назарбаев, Армении — Серж Саргсян, а также премьер-министр Кыргызстана Сапар Исаков.*

Comment: А какие еще есть варианты перестроить предложение?

Comment: Мне сложно придумать хотя бы один ещё вариант. Вот посмотрите, что shampar предложил. Не знаю, насколько годится перестановка ВЕЭС, действительно ли неважно, чтобы было именно заседание ВЕЭС. Если да, то тоже вариант. Только я бы поставил двоеточие вместо тире (традиционный выбор).

Comment: Думаю, так звучит лучше:  В заседании ВЕЭС участвовали: президент России Владимир Путин, Беларуси — Александр Лукашенко, Казахстана — Нурсултан Назарбаев, Армении — Серж Саргсян, а также премьер-министр Кыргызстана Сапар Исаков

Comment: Почему нехорош вариант с двоеточием после слова "президенты"? По правилам, после перечисления, находящегося в середине предложения, нужно ставить тире (президенты: а,б,в, – а также премьер...), но у нас тире используется в самом перечислении. См. § 174 (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire).

Comment: @М_Г, а кто сказал, что плох вариант с двоеточием?

Comment: Кстати, мне нравится Ваш вариант (тот, что "мой с поправкой")! Поставил плюсик.

Comment: Кто сказал? Это просто мое мнение. Вариант с двоеточием именно после слова "президенты" мне не нравится, поэтому я переставил двоеточие, эта маленькая правка решает проблему, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Ну, тут в любом случае перечисление не в середине предложения, а в конце.

Comment: Если обобщающее слово – *президенты* (после него двоеточие), то перечислением президентов предложение не заканчивается.

Comment: Перечислением президентов не заканчивается, но перечислением всех действующих лиц — заканчивается. Странно всё-таки выделять тире президентов и упоминать премьер-министра после второго тире. По-моему, это совсем не тот случай, что со станицами.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, наиболее точный и официальный вариант таков:

*В заседании ВЕЭС участвовали президент России Владимир Путин, президент Беларуси Александр Лукашенко, президент Казахстана Нурсултан Назарбаев, президент Армении Серж Саргсян и премьер-министр Кыргызстана Сапар Исаков.*

А если не требовать строгой официальности, то возможен вариант, предложенный Артёмом Луговым, с небольшой поправкой:

*В заседании ВЕЭС участвовали: президент России Владимир Путин, Беларуси — Александр Лукашенко, Казахстана — Нурсултан Назарбаев, Армении — Серж Саргсян, а также премьер-министр Кыргызстана Сапар Исаков*

Примечание: неудачен, на мой взгляд, вариант типа "президент Владимир Путин (Россия)". Возможно: "президент России Владимир Путин" или "Владимир Путин, президент России"

Дополнение.
Вот нашел, на сайте президента пишут: "[Президенты России Владимир Путин и Алжира Абдельазиз Бутефлика провели переговоры в Кремле](http://kremlin.ru/events/president/news/43836)". На мой взгляд, так писать неверно, но раз уж такой сайт это себе позволяет, то и Вы, Наталья, можете оставить свой исходный вариант.